# Autologin in web after the first succesful login

Tags: android, cookies, webview, android-webview

I need to login into a certain website with autologin. 
I mean the firsttime i login my app asks for authentication. And after the first login the webapp will remember me and is going to auto login. I don't know where to start.

```
  webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(webview, url);
        }
    });
    CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getContext());
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieSyncManager.sync();

    String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(Url);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.loadUrl(Url);
```

Comment: you have use api to do this.. Make a custom url with login information that will redirect to original website with login.

Comment: In this linked youtube series they cover the subject about auto logging in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEZEahTzuck

Comment: am using post request to api to login app and don't know how to make webview  login cookie and remove older one

Comment: sorry my title was ittle wrong i wanted to auto login webview after login app @Muhaiminurabir